Can i put ios build from unity in appclip?
I'm trying to put a Unity ios build in the app clip, and I don't see that anyone has done it before, if someone has managed to put it in the App clip, can you inform me how they managed to put it
I have set Build in App Clip but how to call Build to show in AppClip I can't figure out
